# Dados não aparecem no DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

Tenho DataGridView em dois Forms do meu projeto, porém só aparecem os dados em um, e no outro não está aparecendo, já revisei tudo mas parece tudo certo pra mim.

Código do Load do Form

```
    private void CriarOrc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dgv_produtos1.DataSource = Banco.ObterProdutosGrid();
        
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[0].Width = 70;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[1].Width = 250;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[2].Width = 70;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[3].Width = 80;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[4].Width = 70;


    }
```

Código da classe Banco

```
   public static DataTable ObterProdutosGrid()
        {
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                var vcon = ConexaoBanco();
                var cmd = vcon.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT idprod as 'ID Produto', nome as 'Nome', medida as 'Medida', qtd as 'Quantidade', valor as 'Valor' FROM tb_produto";
                da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, vcon);
                da.Fill(dt);
                vcon.Close();
                return dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONSEGUI POR MEIO DE UM BOTÃO. COLOQUEI O BOTÃO VISUALIZAR E CODIFIQUEI O BOTÃO NORMALMENTE E DEU CERTO.
AINDA NÃO SEI PORQUE NAO APARECEU NO LOAD, MAS ESSA FOI A SOLUÇÃO QUE ENCONTREI.

```
 private void btn_visualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dgv_produtos1.DataSource = Banco.ObterProdutosGrid();
        
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[0].Width = 70;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[1].Width = 250;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[2].Width = 70;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[3].Width = 80;
        dgv_produtos1.Columns[4].Width = 70;


    }
```